# Node.js library for fingerprint scanning

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am building an application using node.js and angular .i have to scan fingerprints of users and save them. But still i found nothing about node.js fingerprint scanning library.
If anyone know how to integrate this functionality please guide me

Comment: What fingerprint scanner hardware are you using?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a "Node.js fingerprint scanning library." You're going to find appropriate hardware that has some way to access the data on the web (i.e. the manufacturer provides a cloud dashboard with API endpoints that the data uploads to). In this scenario, Node would only come into the picture when you hit those endpoints and receive the data, at which point you could process them however you like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get data from a fingerprint scanner in to a NodeJS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720934/how-can-i-get-data-from-a-fingerprint-scanner-in-to-a-nodejs-application)

Comment: How can I get data from a fingerprint scanner in to a NodeJS application? -> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Check out WebAuthn it is still not well supported because it's very new but it's there. From what i gather it will enable biometric signins and signups.
Here are some useful links:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/webauthn

And here is a demo:

https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/

Click register new credential and it will ask for user touch.